# Cloudflare Stream API Webhooks Not Working

Tags: cloudflare

I'm having trouble setting a Webhook URL for the Cloudflare Stream product. I am receiving an 10012 error when attempting to access the API endpoint.

I'm following the documentation located here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/webhooks/

Here's the example cURL call I make:

```
curl -X "PUT" "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{MY_ACCOUNT}/media/webhook" \
     -H 'X-Auth-Key: {MY_AUTH_KEY}' \
     -H 'X-Auth-Email: {MY_EMAIL}' \
     -d "{\"notification_url\":\"{A_URL}\"}"
```

The response received is:

```
{
    "result": null,
    "success": false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 10012,
            "message": "Forbidden"
        }
    ],
    "messages": null
}
```

I'm confident that I am entering the correct authentication key, account ID, etc. It's all copy/pasted from dash.cloudflare.com and have verified that this API key works on other API endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a ticket and they replied after they “made some internal configuration changes” and now the webhook API endpoints work flawlessly. Thanks for the quick help, Cloudflare!